# NSButton does not respond to MouseDown Events if it is a part of custom NSView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton, mousedown

I have an OS X application with a main view (i.e., self.view) that contains an NSScrollView and the NSScrollView contains a custom NSView. The custom NSView (flippedNSView) is just an NSView custom class FlippedNSView with a -(BOOL)isFlipped { return YES; }

I have a function that creates a NSButton that is called in the ViewDidLoad.
If button is added to self.view, button works fine
If button is added to flippedNSView, button does not respond.
NSTextViews work fine and respond to MouseDown events, although they do not respond to text selection. Only the buttons do not respond.

Any ideas?

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "CodeObjViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    FlippedView *flippedNSView;
}
// Windows are defined in MainMenu.xib with the following hierarchy
// Window
//   |_ View
//        |_ flippedNSView
//        |_ scrollView
//        |_ myCustomView
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSViewController *myViewController;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myCustomView;
@property(readwrite, strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSScrollView* scrollView;
@property(readwrite, strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FlippedView * flippedNSView;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize flippedNSView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _myViewController = [[CodeObjViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"customViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_myCustomView addSubview:[_myViewController view]];
    [[_myViewController view] setFrame:[_myCustomView bounds]];
    [scrollView setDocumentView: flippedNSView];   
}
```

customViewController.h

```
@interface FlippedView : NSView
@end
//----------------------------------------------------------
@interface CodeObjViewController : NSViewController {
    FlippedView *flippedNSView;
    NSScrollView *scrollView;
}
```

customViewController.m

```
@implementation FlippedView
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
- (BOOL)isFlipped {
    return YES;
}
@end

//----------------------------------------------------------
@implementation customViewController
// Custom View Controller
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    // The scroll and flipped views are defined on menu.xib and declared on the AppDelegate.
    AppDelegate *theAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    flippedNSView = theAppDelegate.flippedNSView;
    scrollView = theAppDelegate.scrollView;

    NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,10,10)];

    [self.view     addSubview:helpButton];  // THIS RESPONDS TO MOUSE DOWN
    [flippedNSView addSubview:helpButton];  // THIS DOES NOT RESPOND TO MOUSE DOWN

    [button setAction:@selector(buttonClicked:)];
    [button setTarget:self];
}
-(void) buttonClicked : (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Button clicked");
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are setting the action and target of a variable named 'helpButton' instead of 'button'

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo on the helpButton. The action and targets were on button. I have corrected it on the sample code above.

Comment: Can we please see the `@interface` part of the class shown above, specifically where the properties like `flippedNSView`, `parentView`, etc. are defined? Also, when you say "If `parentView` is set as `flippedNSView`..." where are how are you "setting" the value of `parentView`? As an IBOutlet, or in code? If code, please provide it...

Comment: I made some edits to show the view hierarchy. There was nothing wrong with the function that created the NSButton and I removed it.

Comment: I added the AppDelegate.m and .h because probably play a significant role on all this. flippedNSView is a custom View of class FlippedView

Comment: Your sample code still has the typo.